# How to ALTER ROLE for many roles?

Tags: postgresql

I have about 400 roles in Postgres that I want to modify. I can run the following command 400 times, but I was wondering if there is some better way.

```
ALTER ROLE foo CONNECTION LIMIT 4;
```

Something along the lines of

```
UPDATE roles SET connection_limit = 4 WHERE connection_limit = 2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `psql` and its little-known `\gexec` functionality:

```
SELECT format('ALTER ROLE %I CONNECTION LIMIT 4', rolname)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles
WHERE rolconnlimit = 2\gexec
```

That will run the query and execute each result string as SQL command.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this will work on postgres 9.5? It sounds like gexec is only available on 9.6+.

Comment: Yes, that's 9.6 and later. For earlier versions, create a script with `\o` and run it with `\i`.